# MissingSchemaError in Nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

hello everyone i'm not able specify relation to another model. when i add a relation it's showing me this error

Book Model

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type BookDocument = Book & Document;
@Schema({ timestamps: true, collection: 'books' })
export class Book {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  author: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  bookType: string;
}

export const BooksSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Book);
```

BookLend Model

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Schema as mongooseSchema, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Book } from '../../books/enitiy/book.model';
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export type BookLendDocument = BookLend & Document;

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class BookLend {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Prop({ type: mongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'books', required: true })
  bookId: Book;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  returnDate: string;

  @Prop({ type: String })
  returnedOn: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  status: string;
}

export const BookLendSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(BookLend);
```

i'm referring the books objectID to booklend booksID , when i use below code i'm getting error `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "books".`

```
 const allBookLendDetails = await this.bookLend
      .find()
      .populate('bookId')
      .exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

hi guy's I fixed it by importing the `BooksSchema` into `BookLend` Module file
here ref code:-

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BookLendService } from './book-lend.service';
import { BookLendController } from './book-lend.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { BookLendSchema } from './entities/book-lend.entity';
import { CommonService } from '../common-service/common-service.service';
import { BooksSchema } from '../books/enitiy/book.model';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: 'booklend', schema: BookLendSchema },
      { name: 'books', schema: BooksSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [BookLendController],
  providers: [BookLendService, CommonService],
})
export class BookLendModule {}
```

In the service file, you need to inject the model

```
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('booklend') private readonly bookLend: Model<BookLend>,
    @InjectModel('books') private readonly books: Model<Book>
  ) {}
```